# Rails ignoring whitespace before <%= inserts

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I like my view-source code to be nice an clean but any time I use <%= => tags the whitespace before that tag is ignored.

.html.erb: [image: .html.erb file]

View-Source: [image: Source]

Notice the Yield, crfs_meta, and stylesheet link tags ignore the whitespace before the tag. I am using standard 2 spaces as my "tab". For the Yield and when I render partials I can just compensate for the removed whitespace and put it in the partial, but I can't do that for the script and style sheet tags. Is there a way to make is keep my whitespace???

I just realized that the render tag for a layout and yield keeps the whitespace of the previous line (4 tabs, render is on 6 tabs) but inside that layout I have to put the first line at 0 tab, then the next line at 4 tabs, to get it inline at 6 tabs...

Comment: Rails 4, Ruby 2.9.3, Aptana Studio 3 is my IDE

Comment: Your images are neat but it would be easier as an answerer if the code were presented in "stackoverflow style" as a block of actual text. It makes it easier then to copy your specific code into an answer. It also encourages you to distil your question code down to the specific problem ;)

Comment: I can understand that Shadwell but stack overflow also strips the whitespace and I wasn't going to go in and reformat the whitespace again.

Comment: Heh, yeah, it would have been confusing for the whitespace to have been stripped from the question too!

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't strip whitespace if you format your code properly using Markdown. Just indent all of your code by an additional four spaces, or select the code and hit the `{}` button in the toolbar to do it automatically. Then all the whitespace in your code will be preserved, and your code will be syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the `<%=` as your edit suggests. It's because the methods you call in your `<%= ... %>` block are generating more lines of output and those subsequent lines don't respect your indenting.

There's no really neat way to solve it as far as I can tell. You could replace any newlines in the output of those methods with the correct indenting but you are then trading of readability in your code for readability in your output.

For example, something like:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags.gsub("\n", "\n    ").html_safe %>
```

Or you could write a helper method (in application_helper.rb) to do it:

```
def indent_output(output, indentation = "  ")
  output.gsub("\n", "\n" + indentation).html_safe
end
```

And then your relevant view code is:

```
<%= indent_output(csrf_meta_tags, "    ") %>
<%= indent_output(stylesheet_link_tag("bootstrap.min", "main"), "    ") %>
```

Comment: How would I make it so this helper takes a value for the number of spaces to indent? My rails is really rusty.

Comment: Oh wait you did that you just set a default in the helper, I see now!

Comment: Ok so I tried this and 1. the helper needs to be called indent or the tags you supplied called indent_output and then the code came out like this &lt;meta content=&quot;authenticity_token&quot; name=&quot;csrf-param&quot; /&gt;    &lt;meta content=&quot;ATmNHGpQy3193K3KsxndHAc+gzGNoEGw5XmfXi8xKW4=&quot; name=&quot;csrf-token&quot; /&gt;

Comment: Apologies, I forgot that you need to call html_safe on the output of the gsub. I've fixed the method name mixup too.

Comment: Ok cool I modified it just a bit further if you could update ill hit accept. I still need to retain the new lines so I made it add in indentation to new lines 

def indent(output, indentation = "  ")
    output.gsub("\n", "\n"+indentation).html_safe
  end

Comment: You could generate the indentation with `one_indent * num_of_indents`. So your method could be `def indent_output(output, num_indents=1`; `one_indent = "  "`; `indentation = one_indent * num_of_indents`; …. And then you could call it with `<%= indent_output(csrf_meta_tags, 2) %>`

Comment: Yep, that's a good approach too. I still think the whole approach ultimately sacrifices code readability though - but I guess it depends where you value tidiness.